# Ant junit target to run tests having certain pattern?

Tags: junit, ant

I want to my ant junit target to accept a String value from user. This String value will basically be the package name .The junit target should run the test present under this package and not any other test. How do i do the same. Currently , my junit target looks like this:

```
<target name="junit" if="run.junit">
        <junit dir="${project.root}" fork="true">
            <classpath> 
                <path refid="junit.classpath"/>
            </classpath>
            <batchtest >
                <fileset dir="test">
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

How do i modify this to run the tests only as per the given input?

Answer (score 0):

In the `fileset` resources, add an `include` pattern with the package criteria, e.g.:

```
<junit dir="${project.root}" fork="true">
     <classpath> 
         <path refid="junit.classpath"/>
     </classpath>
     <batchtest >
         <fileset dir="test">
            <include name="my/package/**"/>
         </fileset>
     </batchtest>
</junit>
```

See the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) for more examples.